# Declarar Relacionamento Entity Framework um para muitos

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Tenho duas classes: 
Pessoa

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
     ....

    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

Endereço

```
public class Endereco
{
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    public int Cep { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string Quadra { get; set; }
    public string Lote { get; set; }
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    //chave estrangueira
    public int PessoaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

porém estou com dificuldade de fazer esse relacionamento no OnModelCreating
Tanto desses como de outros, a partir desse conseguirei fazer os demais

meu OnModelCreating

```
 // Uma pessoa tem vários endereços
 modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
   .HasOptional(p => p.Endereco)
   .WithMany(e =>
```

Como ficaria o modelBuilder nesse relacionamento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria assim

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>
            .HasMany(p => p.Enderecos)
            .WithRequired() // Porque todo endereço precisa pertencer a uma Pessoa
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PessoaId);
```